# How to merge two different field values into one row?

Tags: mysql, sql, merge

I need to clean some data by merging two similar but slightly different dimension field values into one new row that adds together the two metric values, keeping the uid and date intact.

Current setup looks like this:

```
 ╔═════╦═════════════╦══════╦═══════════╦═══════════╗
 ║ id  ║ date        ║ uid  ║ source    ║ pageviews ║
 ╠═════╬═════════════╬══════╬═══════════╬═══════════╣
 ║  1  ║ 2013-12-11  ║ 111  ║ source1   ║   14      ║
 ║  3  ║ 2013-12-11  ║ 111  ║ source1a  ║   1       ║
 ║  11 ║ 2013-12-11  ║ 222  ║ source1   ║   3       ║
 ║  19 ║ 2013-12-11  ║ 222  ║ source1a  ║   11      ║
 ╚═════╩═════════════╩══════╩═══════════╩═══════════╝
```

I'd like to consider source1 and source1a to be equal and merge the two, to get this:

```
 ╔═════╦═════════════╦══════╦══════════╦═══════════╗
 ║ id  ║ date        ║ uid  ║ source   ║ pageviews ║
 ╠═════╬═════════════╬══════╬══════════╬═══════════╣
 ║  1  ║ 2013-12-11  ║ 111  ║ source1  ║   15      ║
 ║  2  ║ 2013-12-11  ║ 222  ║ source1  ║   14      ║
 ╚═════╩═════════════╩══════╩══════════╩═══════════╝
```

`id` is not important, I had planned to re-increment the id in the new table that results

This is what I tried, but it didn't merge the two records – I am getting matching values but still separate rows:

```
SELECT date, uid, (SELECT CASE
WHEN source = 'source1a' THEN 'source1'
ELSE source
END) AS 'source', pageviews
FROM trafficSourceMedium
GROUP BY date, source, userid
```

Comment: you would need the case statement on the group by too

Comment: Where do '1' and '2' come from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An aggregation query should do what you want:

```
select `date`, uid,
       (case when source = 'source1a' then 'source1' else source end) as source,
       sum(pageviews) as pageviews
from trafficSourceMedium
group by `date`, uid,
          (case when source = 'source1a' then 'source1' else source end);
```